# Android Facebook API - Invalid key problems

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, key

I am trying to implement Facebook into my Android app.

Everytime though, the facebook stuff fails because of an "Invalid key" error although I've been through the steps of setting up an app on FB and getting the key via keytool and so on.

Is there any ideas I can try to fix it ? 
Is it normal for a hash code to have symbols such as '/' or '=' in it?

Comment: If you don't have a luck with using OpenSSL try definitely this: http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have installed your .apk signed in your device, be sure to use the same keystore to sign your app and to get the Key hash, and yes, your key Hash will contain '/' or '=' i.

Comment: Does that include the emulator too ?

Comment: you can´t test your app in your emulator, try installing directly in your device =)

Comment: I think i've done it, I input another command in which it asks for my password and details again and after that i got a "Storing mykey.keystore" message, is that right ?

Comment: You can't test a FB app in the emulator ?

Comment: @Jorgesys I use in emulator all the time, that's why they supply facebook apk file for install in emulator